# Throw exception 'cuDNN failure 8: CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED' in training ONNX's pretrained model Emotion FerPlus

Tags: cntk, onnx, onnxruntime

I am testing to train `Emotion FerPlus` emotion recognition model.
Training has `cuDNN failure 8: CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED` error.
I am using `Nvidia GPU TitanRTX 24G`.
Then change the `minibatch_size from 32 to 1`. But still have error.
I am using CNTK-GPU docker.
The complete error messages are

```
About to throw exception 'cuDNN failure 8: CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED ; GPU=0 ; hostname=d9150da5d531 ; expr=cudnnConvolutionForward(*m_cudnn, &C::One, m_inT, ptr(in), *m_kernelT, ptr(kernel), *m_conv, m_fwdAlgo.selectedAlgo, ptr(workspace), workspace.BufferSize(), &C::Zero, m_outT, ptr(out))'
cuDNN failure 8: CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED ; GPU=0 ; hostname=d9150da5d531 ; expr=cudnnConvolutionForward(*m_cudnn, &C::One, m_inT, ptr(in), *m_kernelT, ptr(kernel), *m_conv, m_fwdAlgo.selectedAlgo, ptr(workspace), workspace.BufferSize(), &C::Zero, m_outT, ptr(out))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 193, in <module>
    main(args.base_folder, args.training_mode)
  File "train.py", line 124, in main
    trainer.train_minibatch({input_var : images, label_var : labels})
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cntk/train/trainer.py", line 184, in train_minibatch
    device)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cntk/cntk_py.py", line 3065, in train_minibatch
    return _cntk_py.Trainer_train_minibatch(self, *args)
RuntimeError: cuDNN failure 8: CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED ; GPU=0 ; hostname=d9150da5d531 ; expr=cudnnConvolutionForward(*m_cudnn, &C::One, m_inT, ptr(in), *m_kernelT, ptr(kernel), *m_conv, m_fwdAlgo.selectedAlgo, ptr(workspace), workspace.BufferSize(), &C::Zero, m_outT, ptr(out))

[CALL STACK]
[0x7fc04da7ce89]                                                       + 0x732e89
[0x7fc045a71aaf]                                                       + 0xeabaaf
[0x7fc045a7b613]    Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::CuDnnConvolutionEngine<float>::  ForwardCore  (Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::Matrix<float> const&,  Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::Matrix<float> const&,  Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::Matrix<float>&,  Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::Matrix<float>&) + 0x1a3
[0x7fc04dd4f8d3]    Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ConvolutionNode<float>::  ForwardProp  (Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::FrameRange const&) + 0xa3
[0x7fc04dfba654]    Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNetwork::PARTraversalFlowControlNode::  ForwardProp  (std::shared_ptr<Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNodeBase> const&,  Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::FrameRange const&) + 0xf4
[0x7fc04dcb6e33]    std::_Function_handler<void (std::shared_ptr<Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNodeBase> const&),void Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNetwork::ForwardProp<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNodeBase>,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNodeBase>>>>(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNodeBase>,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNodeBase>>> const&)::{lambda(std::shared_ptr<Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNodeBase> const&)#1}>::  _M_invoke  (std::_Any_data const&,  std::shared_ptr<Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNodeBase> const&) + 0x63
[0x7fc04dd04ed9]    void Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNetwork::  TravserseInSortedGlobalEvalOrder  <std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNodeBase>,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNodeBase>>>>(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNodeBase>,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNodeBase>>> const&,  std::function<void (std::shared_ptr<Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::ComputationNodeBase> const&)> const&) + 0x5b9
[0x7fc04dca64da]    CNTK::CompositeFunction::  Forward  (std::unordered_map<CNTK::Variable,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<std::pair<CNTK::Variable const,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>>>> const&,  std::unordered_map<CNTK::Variable,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<std::pair<CNTK::Variable const,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>>>>&,  CNTK::DeviceDescriptor const&,  std::unordered_set<CNTK::Variable,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<CNTK::Variable>> const&,  std::unordered_set<CNTK::Variable,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<CNTK::Variable>> const&) + 0x15da
[0x7fc04dc3d603]    CNTK::Function::  Forward  (std::unordered_map<CNTK::Variable,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<std::pair<CNTK::Variable const,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>>>> const&,  std::unordered_map<CNTK::Variable,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<std::pair<CNTK::Variable const,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>>>>&,  CNTK::DeviceDescriptor const&,  std::unordered_set<CNTK::Variable,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<CNTK::Variable>> const&,  std::unordered_set<CNTK::Variable,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<CNTK::Variable>> const&) + 0x93
[0x7fc04ddbf91b]    CNTK::Trainer::  ExecuteForwardBackward  (std::unordered_map<CNTK::Variable,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<std::pair<CNTK::Variable const,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>>>> const&,  std::unordered_map<CNTK::Variable,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<std::pair<CNTK::Variable const,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>>>>&,  CNTK::DeviceDescriptor const&,  std::unordered_map<CNTK::Variable,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<std::pair<CNTK::Variable const,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>>>>&) + 0x36b
[0x7fc04ddc06e4]    CNTK::Trainer::  TrainLocalMinibatch  (std::unordered_map<CNTK::Variable,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<std::pair<CNTK::Variable const,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>>>> const&,  std::unordered_map<CNTK::Variable,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<std::pair<CNTK::Variable const,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>>>>&,  bool,  CNTK::DeviceDescriptor const&) + 0x94
[0x7fc04ddc178a]    CNTK::Trainer::  TrainMinibatch  (std::unordered_map<CNTK::Variable,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<std::pair<CNTK::Variable const,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>>>> const&,  bool,  std::unordered_map<CNTK::Variable,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<std::pair<CNTK::Variable const,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>>>>&,  CNTK::DeviceDescriptor const&) + 0x5a
[0x7fc04ddc1852]    CNTK::Trainer::  TrainMinibatch  (std::unordered_map<CNTK::Variable,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>,std::hash<CNTK::Variable>,std::equal_to<CNTK::Variable>,std::allocator<std::pair<CNTK::Variable const,std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Value>>>> const&,  bool,  CNTK::DeviceDescriptor const&) + 0x52
[0x7fc04eb2db22]                                                       + 0x229b22
[0x7fc057ea15e9]    PyCFunction_Call                                   + 0xf9
[0x7fc057f267c0]    PyEval_EvalFrameEx                                 + 0x6ba0
[0x7fc057f29b49]                                                       + 0x144b49
[0x7fc057f28df5]    PyEval_EvalFrameEx                                 + 0x91d5
[0x7fc057f29b49]                                                       + 0x144b49
[0x7fc057f28df5]    PyEval_EvalFrameEx                                 + 0x91d5
[0x7fc057f29b49]                                                       + 0x144b49
[0x7fc057f28df5]    PyEval_EvalFrameEx                                 + 0x91d5
[0x7fc057f29b49]                                                       + 0x144b49
[0x7fc057f29cd8]    PyEval_EvalCodeEx                                  + 0x48
[0x7fc057f29d1b]    PyEval_EvalCode                                    + 0x3b
[0x7fc057f4f020]    PyRun_FileExFlags                                  + 0x130
[0x7fc057f50623]    PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags                            + 0x173
[0x7fc057f6b8c7]    Py_Main                                            + 0xca7
[0x400add]          main                                               + 0x15d
[0x7fc056f06830]    __libc_start_main                                  + 0xf0
[0x4008b9]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CNTK is in maintenance mode now (basically deprecated). While CNTK can export to ONNX pretty OK, importing ONNX models is not really well-supported.

ONNX Runtime https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime now supports training, so please try it. ONNX Runtime training is actively developing and is supported, so if something doesn't quite work, it's likely the issues will be resolved fast.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have CNTK code for training. If ONNX runtime is used, what is the best way to train using ONNX runtime. Would it be able to use the CNTK code directly? Or I have to choose ONNX-Pytorch for training (for example) and convert all lines of code in CNTK train code to Pytorch code and train using ONNX runtime.

Comment: You would have to use PyTorch/ONNX, convert all lines of CNTK code to PyTorch with modifications for ONNXRuntime.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. If I like to test Emotion FerPlus on Nvidia Tensorrt, I have to choose ONNX runtime for LINUX/C++/ x64/TensorRT to build ONNX runtime. Use onnx model directly for tensorrt and do inference, is it? Where can I have Emotion FerPlus test code? The src code provided doesn't include test.pyy, especially the parser part for Tensorrt output.

Comment: For training, CUDA execution provider should work. You can probably just install with `pip install onnxruntime-gpu`. Then you can save model at the end of training to ONNX format, and use with TensorRT execution provider for inference (see https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/master/docs/execution_providers/TensorRT-ExecutionProvider.md; not sure how faster it will be compared to CUDA execution provider).

Comment: You meant, convert CNTK code to Pytorch and train using CUDA execution provider?But for Tensorrt deployment I can just use ONNX model from model zoo and deploy at tensorrt, right?

Comment: Yes, convert CNTK code to PyTorch with ONNX Runtime changes and train using CUDA execution provider. Then save the model in ONNX - it will be the same as zoo's model, just with updated weights. Then you can use that model with TensortRT the same way you would use the zoo's model.

Comment: My last query, Where can I have test code for Emotion FerPlus. Provided source codes don't include test code.

Comment: I don't know that, sorry. Maybe open an issue in that GitHub repo?